# Bash script to find element of list that appears first in a second list

Tags: shell-script

I have a list of numbers (no duplicates) `val_str="11 22 33"` that can be stored as an array if needed, e.g.: `val_arr=(11 22 33)`.

I have a second list of numbers that come from a field in a tab-delimited file. I can write these numbers to a separate file if necessary using `awk`. Here are some toy data:

```
echo -e "66\n55\n99\n33\n11\n88\n77\n22\n33" > list
```

I want to find the value of the element in `val_arr` that occurs first in `list`. It is possible that some elements of `val_arr` will not appear in `list`. The code below works if all elements of `val_arr` appear in `list`, but fails if this is not the case, e.g. if `val_arr=(11 44 22 33)`.

```
val_arr=(11 22 33)
echo -e "66\n55\n99\n33\n11\n88\n77\n22\n33" > list
pos_arr=()
for i in ${!val_arr[@]}; do
    list_pos=$(grep -nm 1 ${val_arr[$i]} list | cut -f1 -d:)
    pos_arr+=( ${list_pos} )
done

pos1=$(echo ${pos_arr[@]} | tr ' ' '\n' | awk 'NR==1 {min=$0} NR>1 && $1<min {min=$1; pos=NR} END {print pos}')
pos0=$(( pos1 - 1 ))
val=${val_arr[$pos0]}
```

In the case of both `val_arr=(11 22 33)` and `val_arr=(11 44 22 33)` I want the script to return `33`.

My questions are:

1. Is there a better way to do this?
2. Is there a way to make this code robust to missing values (something more elegant than appending all values in `val_arry` to the end of `list` with `echo ${pos_arr[@]} | tr ' ' '\n' >> list`)?

Thanks!

P.S. Thanks to @Adrian Frühwirth for the `awk` code above from here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16610162/bash-return-position-of-the-smallest-entry-in-an-array

Comment: What do you need exactly though? You seem to be saving some things but don't ever use them. Do you only need the first match or do you want to find all matches? Your question asks about the first match but your code is storing all matches and their positions. Do you need that information too?

Comment: I don't need all the data, just the value of the element that appears first. I just didn't know a better way to find the first element without storing all positions and then checking which is first. I've updated the question to clarify this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about turning `val_arr` into a grep pattern or list of expressions

```
$ echo "${val_arr[@]/#/-e}"
-e11 -e44 -e22 -e33
```

and using that directly?

```
$ grep -wFm1 "${val_arr[@]/#/-e}" list
33
```

Comment: In the actual case, I'm converting the list of numbers from a given string (`val_string="11 22 33)`) to the array using `read -ra val_arr <<< ${val_string}`. Looks like that isn't necessary. What is `${val_arr[@]/#/-e}` doing?

Comment: @Josh `${val_arr[@]/#/-e}` substitutes `-e` before each element of the array. if you are actually starting from a space-separated string, then it would be simpler to convert it to a regex pattern ex. `grep -m1 "${val_string[@]// /\\|}" list` and avoid the array altogether. This is essentially [@terdon's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/581757/65304).

Comment: I'm not sure our approach works, actually: `printf '11\n22\n33\n' | grep -wEm1 '11|22|33'` returns 33, but that is the last match, not the first one.

Comment: `33` appears twice, in the 4th position and the last position. Your code is perfect in my testing. I just don't know who to give the right answer to, since I'm using a combination of your answers!

Comment: I'm using `grp_str="${val_str// /\\|}"; 
grep -wm1 "$grp_str" list` without the `-E` for extended regex, and `grep` seems to be handling the `|` fine. Is `-E` necessary?

Comment: @Josh `"${val_str// /\\|}"` inserts *escaped* `\|` which is what you need for basic grep - you can use `"${val_str// /|}"` with extended grep if you prefer

Comment: @Josh oh, duh! I completely missed that it appeared twice! And don't worry, accept steeldriver's, I have more rep than I need anyway, and this answer is fine!

Comment: @terdon thanks for adding the `-w` (which I missed in my later comment as well - oops)

Answer (score 4):

I would just use `grep` and convert the array to a string:

```
#!/bin/bash
val_arr=(11 22 33)

grep_string=$(tr ' ' '|' <<<"${val_arr[@]}")

first_found=$(grep -wEm1 "$grep_string" list);
if [[ -z $first_found ]]; then
  echo "None of the numbers were found"
else
  echo "Found: $first_found"
fi
```

The `tr` command will convert the array into a list of elements separated by `|`:

```
$ grep_string=$(tr ' ' '|' <<<"${val_arr[@]}")
$ echo $grep_string 
11|22|33
```

This can then be passed to `grep -E`. The options used are:

- `-E`: enable extended regular expressions so we can use `|` to mean "OR".
- `-w`: only match entire words, so that `3` doesn't match `33`. You could also use `-x` (match entire line) instead, depending on your input.
- `-m1`: stop after the first match.

If you also want the position in the file, add `-n` so it will also print the line number.